# Convergence of a sequence given that of certain subsequences

Tags: real-analysis

I am interested in the following problem: let $A$ be a subset of $(1,+\infty)$ and $u$ a sequence of real numbers. Denote for any $a \in A$, $u(a)$ the subsequence of u defined through the extraction $\varphi(n) = [an]$ (denoting $[x]$ the integrer part, or floor function,  of $x$) -- that is $u_n(a) = u_{[an]}$.

Assume that, for any $a\in A$, the subsequence $u(a)$ converges (without assuming apriori that the limit is independent of $a$, but if it simplifies a proof, I am happy with a solution based on the independence of $\lim u(a)$ wrt $a$ as well). Must $u$ converge as well?

Of course, it is too general, and the answer is no if $A$ is finite, or if $A = \bf N\setminus\{1\}$. But the answer is yes if $A$ = irrationals $>1$, which can be proven by Baire theorem, or using the Beatti partition theorem (but these proofs don not entirely satisfy me as they seem to me too involved given the amount of hypotheses).

I though the case $A = \bf Q\cap (1,+\infty)$ would be easier (I suspect the answer is no) but I don't find a proof...

If anyone has an idea, or a hint, it would certainly help me! Also, I don't know if this question is well known, but does there exist necessary or sufficient conditions on $A$ insuring the answer is yes?

Thanks!